# Workaround for mysql create trigger if not exist?

Tags: mysql

In my application I have a dynamic system, so I have to check if a table is already existing and exceptionally create it on demand. This is no problem by doing a create table if not exists.

But since mysql does not support "if not exists" in the create trigger statement, I want to ask if there is another workaround than dropping the trigger? It makes no sense to me to drop a trigger to recreate it every time, I just want to create a missing trigger. This event should happen once while a drop and recreate will happen often. The trigger is neccessary for audit/logging purpose.

Maybe we can do it in oracle way, where you could wrap the create ddl in a begin/end and then do null in the exception hanlder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CREATE TRIGGER statement. If trigger exists you will get an exception, just catch it.

If you do not want to catch errors, then you may check existence -

```
SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'trigger_name'
```

Comment: I will do it the way along selecting for existing trigger. Thnaks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the triggers when you create the table, if you drop a table with triggers drop fails, you must drop triggers before.

Create the triggers when create the table and if table exists triggers exists

Answer (score 0):

Starting from MySQL 8.0.29 the CREATE TRIGGER statement supports `IF NOT EXISTS` clasue:

[CREATE TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> ```
> CREATE
> [DEFINER = user]
> TRIGGER [IF NOT EXISTS] trigger_name
> ```
>
> IF NOT EXISTS prevents an error from occurring if a trigger having the same name, on the same table, exists in the same schema. This option is supported with CREATE TRIGGER beginning with MySQL 8.0.29.